# How to add SObject records to lwc data table based on input from user

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

How can I add records to a lwc data table based on input,
for example, I have a search input text on my component that looks for a custom object,
and I need to add that specific custom object record to the data-table once the record is selected on the search input, how can I accomplish this considering that I already know what are the columns that I need to display on the table?

Comment: Please let me know if I need to provide more information about my question.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Are your searched SObjects same SObject or not?

If you are searching the same SObject with different records, when you select a record, add your selected record's data to your data array.

Since you already know how data-table works. I will give you a simple code example:

```
columns = [
{ label: 'Id', fieldName: 'Id', type: 'text'},
{ label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'}
]
@track
records = [
{Id: 1, Name: record1}
]
// your input onchange event handler
onChange(e) {
  var input = e.detail.value
  // an @AuraEnable method in your apex
  getRecordInfo({inputInfo: input}).then(result => {
    // in your apex method you should return a SObject type
    this.records.push(result)
  }.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
  )
}
```

If your SObjects are in diffent types, you should make sure their fields' names are the same.